# How to make printing the same on any printer?

Tags: c++, winapi

Ive been using `HORZRES` and `VERTRES` to print various strings. I had been using xps to test my printing and such but when I switched over to my actually computer I noticed that things werent printing the same.

> **How do you get the size of the actual page and print from there?**

For example if I was printing from a letter(8 1/2 x 12 inches) How could I get a universal measurement that could be used for any printer

Comment: It might help if you showed some of the code that you have written. It is possible you are not using HORZRES and VERTRES correctly.

Comment: Basically if I call cout<<GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,VERTRES/HORZRES) I get two different values depending on if i choose the xps printer or my printer.

Comment: You need to make your question more specific.  How are you using those values to print strings? In what ways is the output from your printer different than from the XPS imager?  What do you mean by "get a universal measurement"?

Comment: What do you mean by "printing the same"? Do you mean you want the same number of chars to be printed on a line? If so, then you will have to scale the font size you use for the text.

Comment: No. GetDeviceCaps(pdx.hDC,VERTRES) returns an int. GetDeviceCaps returns a different value when I select my printer under the PRINTDLGEX window, and it returns a different value when I select the MICROSOFT xps printer. Because VERTRES returns the resolution relative to the printer, not the physical size of the page being printed on,as stated in the documentation. I was asking if there was any way to return the actual physical size of the page being printed on, instead of the resolution that is different between printers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SetMapMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the mapping mode.

If you set the mapping mode to, say, `MM_LOENGLISH` then all drawing will be in units of 1/100 inch.  A line drawn with length 100 will then be one inch long on any printer, and you don't need to worry about the printer's resolution.

If you want further information about the page you can get other data from `GetDeviceCaps`:

- `LOGPIXELSX` - horizontal pixels per inch
- `LOGPIXELSY` - vertical pixels per inch
- `PHYSICALWIDTH` - width of the page in device units
- `PHYSICALHEIGHT` - height of the page in device units

Then the width of the page in inches is `PHYSICALWIDTH / LOGPIXELSX` and the height is `PHYSICALHEIGHT / LOGPIXELSY`.

Comment: Also, PHYSICALOFFSETX and PHYSICALOFFSETY tell you how far from the origin is from the physical corner of the page.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy If you are going to be picky, the physical corner of the page is always no distance from the origin.  i.e. the corner of the page is always at (0,0).  PHYSICALOFFSET? give you the corner of the printable area.  Of course, these aren't much use without HORZRES and VERTRES, which give you the size of the printable area.

Comment: @arx:  Most printers cannot print to the very edges of the paper.  Assuming MM_TEXT, logical coordinate (0, 0) is generally to the right and down from the physical top-left corner of the paper.  PHYSICALOFFSETX and PHYSICALOFFSETY tell you how far (0, 0) is from the corner for this particular printer.  HORZRES and VERTRES tell you how many pixels are in the physical range of the printer.  The offsets and the resolutions together effectively give you the printable area of the page.  PHYSICALWIDTH and PHYSICALHEIGHT tell you how large the paper is.

Comment: It's intentional that (0, 0) is the first pixel in the printable area rather than the corner of the page.  It's done that way to help simple programs that don't check the physical margins and just assume they can print to (0, 0).  All of those programs would have clipped output if (0, 0) were actually the corner of the page, which is probably outside the printable area.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy My apologies, you are right.  It's a long while since I did any GDI printing and the docs are vague.  I just looked at some of my old code and although it calculates layout relative to the corner of the paper, it then translates the coordinates into "printable area space" to account for the location of the origin.